# Using "string_view" to represent the "string" key

Tags: c++, protobuf-c

When I use `map<string, string> kv;` in protobuf 3.8.0, the next code works:

```
std::string_view key("key");
kv[key] = "value";
```

While in protobuf 3.19.4, the above code doesn't work.

The error msg is:

> error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'google::protobuf::Map<std::__cxx11::basic_string
> , std::__cxx11::basic_string>' and 'std::string_view' {aka 'std::basic_string_view'})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 3.8.0, `Map::operator[]` is declared as:

```
Value& operator[](const Key& k)
```

Where, in your case, `Key` is `std::string`. `std::string_view` is convertible to `std::string`, which is why the code works in 3.8.0.

In 3.19.4, `Map::operator[]` is declared as:

```
template <typename K = key_type>
T& operator[](const key_arg<K>& key)

template <
    typename K = key_type,
    // Disable for integral types to reduce code bloat.
    typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<K>::value>::type>
T& operator[](key_arg<K>&& key)
```

Where `key_arg` is declared as:

```
template <typename LookupKey>
using key_arg = typename internal::TransparentSupport<key_type>::template key_arg<LookupKey>;
```

And, in your case, `key_type` is `std::string`. `std::string_view` is not convertible to `TransparentSupport::key_arg`, which is why the code doesn't work in 3.19.4.